# Collection of sorting types

Tags: c++, c++11, sorting

A collection of sorting types as following insertion, radix, selection and heap sorts.

How can i improve it?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>


template <typename Iterator>
void radixSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        std::stable_partition(begin, end,
            [&](value_type& value)
        {
            if (i == 31) 
                return value < 0; 
            else
                return !(value & (1 << i));
        });
    }
}

template<typename Iterator>
void insertionSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        std::rotate(std::upper_bound(begin, i, *i, std::less<value_type>()), i, std::next(i));
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void selectionSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        const auto minElemt(std::min_element(begin, end, std::less<value_type>()));

        if (begin != minElemt)
        {
            std::iter_swap(begin, minElemt);
        }
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void heapSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    std::make_heap(begin, end, std::less<value_type>());
    std::sort_heap(begin, end, std::less<value_type>());
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {9,-6, 7, -8, 6, -9, 1, 3, -4, 2, -1, -5, 5, 8, -3, 4, 0, -2, -7 };

    radixSort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    //insertionSort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    //selectionSort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    //heapSort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));

    for (const auto& i : a)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `radixSort` implicitly assumes that all `value_type`s are 32-bit signed integers, I would recommend something like `static_assert(std::is_same<value_type, int32_t>::value, "Wrong type");` and to make it work for more types.

Comment: @nwp  good point. i will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In radixSort you assume that `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` is a signed 32bit int.

Instead you should check whether it's an integral type and alter the algorithm a bit based on its properties:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void radixSort(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<value_type>::is_integer, "Wrong type");

    for (auto i = 0; i < std::numeric_limits<value_type>::digits; ++i)
    {
        std::stable_partition(begin, end,
            [&](value_type& value)
        {
             return !(value & (1 << i));
        });
    }

    if(std::numeric_limits<value_type>::is_signed){
        std::stable_partition(begin, end,
            [&](value_type& value)
        {
             return value < 0;
        });
    }

}
```

Besides that all your algorithms use the standard `std::less` comparator. you should let the user supply a comparator (a mapping function for `radixSort`) for types that don't have a default `std::less`.